# Jest in a REST API NODEJS couldn't find a Right test for the Controller.js

Tags: node.js, json, rest, unit-testing, jestjs

I created an REST API for logistics controls where is possible to create a truck driver, filter search for specifics drivers based if he is loaded or not, for date and etc.

Now to finish my project i'm trying to create a unit testing for this export module but a couldn't find a right solution:

```
const Driver = require('../models/models.js');

// Create and Save a new driver
exports.create = (req, res) => {

  const { oLongitude, oLatitude } = req.body;
  const { dLongitude, dLatitude } = req.body;

  // Validade request
  if (!Object.keys(req.body).length) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: "Form content can not be empty"
    });
  }

  //Create a driver
  const driver = new Driver({
    name: req.body.name,
    age: req.body.age,
    gender: req.body.gender,
    veichle: req.body.veichle,
    cnhType: req.body.cnhType,
    loaded: req.body.loaded,
    truckType: req.body.truckType,
    origin: {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [oLongitude, oLatitude]
    },
    destination: {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [dLongitude, dLatitude]
    },
    date: req.body.date
  });

  //Save driver in the database
  driver.save()
    .then(data => {
      res.json(data);
    }).catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message || "Some error ocurred while creating the driver."
      });
    });
};
```

This is what i've already tried:

```
const httpMocks = require('node-mocks-http');
const { create } = require('../app/controllers/controller.js');

describe('create', () => {
  test('should create stuff', () => {
    const request = httpMocks.createRequest({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/create'
    });

    const response = httpMocks.createResponse();

    create(request, response, (err) => {
      expect(err).toBeFalsy();
    });

    const { property } = JSON.parse(response._getData());

    expect(property).toBe({
      name: "Antonio dos Santos",
      age: "27",
      gender: "masculino",
      veichle: "nao",
      cnhType: "D",
      loaded: "nao",
      truckType: 2,
      oLongitude: -46.9213486,
      oLatitude: -23.7341936,
      dLongitude: -46.9057519,
      dLatitude: -23.8529033,
      date: "08/02/2020"
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Few things I can see that don't seem quite right - the callback handler passed to `create` in your test won't ever be called, nor would it work this way anyway. You don't appear to be mocking `driver` which means this will be attempting to persist in some DB? (Presumably this is Mongoose).  I'd be inclined to check the status code returned from response, my guess is it's failing because it's trying to actually save the record and something isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the unit test solution:

`controller.js`:

```js
const Driver = require('./models.js');

exports.create = (req, res) => {
  const { oLongitude, oLatitude } = req.body;
  const { dLongitude, dLatitude } = req.body;

  if (!Object.keys(req.body).length) {
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: 'Form content can not be empty',
    });
  }

  const driver = new Driver({
    name: req.body.name,
    age: req.body.age,
    gender: req.body.gender,
    veichle: req.body.veichle,
    cnhType: req.body.cnhType,
    loaded: req.body.loaded,
    truckType: req.body.truckType,
    origin: {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [oLongitude, oLatitude],
    },
    destination: {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [dLongitude, dLatitude],
    },
    date: req.body.date,
  });

  return driver
    .save()
    .then((data) => {
      res.json(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message || 'Some error ocurred while creating the driver.',
      });
    });
};
```

`models.js`:

```js
function Driver() {
  async function save() {
    return 'real implementation';
  }
  return {
    save,
  };
}

module.exports = Driver;
```

`controller.test.js`:

```js
const { create } = require('./controller');
const Driver = require('./models.js');

jest.mock('./models', () => {
  const mDriver = { save: jest.fn() };
  return jest.fn(() => mDriver);
});

describe('60189651', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
  it('should create driver and send to client side', () => {
    expect.assertions(3);
    const mReq = {
      body: {
        name: 'name',
        age: 23,
        gender: 'male',
        veichle: 'BMW',
        cnhType: 'type',
        loaded: true,
        truckType: 'truckType',
        oLatitude: 1,
        oLongitude: 1,
        dLongitude: 2,
        dLatitude: 2,
        date: '2020',
      },
    };
    const mRes = { json: jest.fn() };
    const mDriver = new Driver();
    mDriver.save.mockResolvedValueOnce('saved driver');
    return create(mReq, mRes).then(() => {
      expect(Driver).toBeCalledWith({
        name: 'name',
        age: 23,
        gender: 'male',
        veichle: 'BMW',
        cnhType: 'type',
        loaded: true,
        truckType: 'truckType',
        origin: {
          type: 'Point',
          coordinates: [1, 1],
        },
        destination: {
          type: 'Point',
          coordinates: [2, 2],
        },
        date: '2020',
      });
      expect(mDriver.save).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(mRes.json).toBeCalledWith('saved driver');
    });
  });

  it('should handle error if request body is empty', () => {
    const mReq = { body: {} };
    const mRes = { status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(), json: jest.fn() };
    create(mReq, mRes);
    expect(mRes.status).toBeCalledWith(400);
    expect(mRes.status(400).json).toBeCalledWith({ message: 'Form content can not be empty' });
  });

  it('should handle error if save driver failure', () => {
    expect.assertions(4);
    const mReq = {
      body: {
        name: 'name',
        age: 23,
        gender: 'male',
        veichle: 'BMW',
        cnhType: 'type',
        loaded: true,
        truckType: 'truckType',
        oLatitude: 1,
        oLongitude: 1,
        dLongitude: 2,
        dLatitude: 2,
        date: '2020',
      },
    };
    const mRes = { status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(), send: jest.fn() };
    const mDriver = new Driver();
    const mError = new Error('database connection failure');
    mDriver.save.mockRejectedValueOnce(mError);
    return create(mReq, mRes).then(() => {
      expect(Driver).toBeCalledWith({
        name: 'name',
        age: 23,
        gender: 'male',
        veichle: 'BMW',
        cnhType: 'type',
        loaded: true,
        truckType: 'truckType',
        origin: {
          type: 'Point',
          coordinates: [1, 1],
        },
        destination: {
          type: 'Point',
          coordinates: [2, 2],
        },
        date: '2020',
      });
      expect(mDriver.save).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(mRes.status).toBeCalledWith(500);
      expect(mRes.status(500).send).toBeCalledWith({ message: mError.message });
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/60189651/controller.test.js (6.724s)
  60189651
    ✓ should create driver and send to client side (6ms)
    ✓ should handle error if request body is empty (2ms)
    ✓ should handle error if save driver failure (1ms)

---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |     100 |       75 |     100 |     100 |                   
 controller.js |     100 |       75 |     100 |     100 | 39                
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.747s, estimated 9s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/tree/master/stackoverflow/60189651